# Capture event when the user tries to view page source

Tags: javascript, php, html, user-interface

**Background**: Currently building a web application for a company and thought it would be interesting to see which users are attempting to "peek behind the curtains" so to speak.

I know it's possible to hook into user events whenever they copy things off the page (possibly the most annoying JS control ever) and other various annoying UI actions, but I'm wondering if it's possible to run a JS function (in the background of course) whenever the user tries to view the page source.

Anyone ever tried to do this, or have a better way to do it?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such event, nor is there any way to detect the `view source` url etc. as it's something happening in the browser, and the server never sees any difference.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking. I know there'd be no way to capture it server side, so it'd have to be client-side with JS, but I'm not sure that JS would capture those events happening with the browser and not with the rendered site. Maybe someone else knows though or has an idea..

Comment: you could try context menu then do an ajax call to some sort of logging system.

Comment: `<!-- If you see this, please send an email to YouCanViewSource@example.com -->`

Comment: @epascarello - It actually took a few seconds before I got it, but that's hilarous, and I have actually seen similar things, job offers etc. hidden in the source.

Comment: You can completely bypass any event listeners in Chrome; all you need to do is add `view-source:` to the beginning of the url.